# Regex Question to Grab Keys

Tags: c#, regex

I have this kinda template text :

> Hello {#Name#},
>
> Thanks for coming blah on {#Date#} and
>   we love to see you again here with
>   {#President#}

So I am trying to get `{#...#}` templates parts and put them into an array.

But my expression didn't work :

```
\b(?<=\{\#)(.*)(?=\#\})\b
```

The result became something like this for this sample text :

```
{#Something#} Hello {#Brand#}
```

**Result :**

`Something#} Hello {#Brand`

Comment: FYI: .NET has something very similar built in via data-binding expressions.  See this article for a sample of how to use it: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add ? for laziness like this:

```
\b(?<=\{\#)(.*?)(?=\#\})\b
```

*? [**means**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) that it will search for as few repeats as possible

Comment: @Braveyard - Sorry. One unnecessary bracket. Check again

Answer (score 3):

How about this? `{#([^#]+)#}`

Here's the example used in a PowerShell script:

```
$input = "{#Something#} Hello {#Brand#}"

$match = [regex]::Match($input, "{#([^#]+)#}")

$i = 0

while ($match.Success) {
    $i++
    write-host ("Match {0}: '{1}'" -f $i, $match.Groups[1].Value)
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

And this is what it outputs:

```
Match 1: 'Something'
Match 2: 'Brand'
```

Comment: It didn't work. `{{` is the result. I am using Expresso to evaluate the results.

Comment: I used RegexBuddy - works on my machine! I'll update my answer with a piece of PowerShell to prove the point.

Comment: I think it should be difference between Regex engines? Because `{` should be written with `\\` to indicate that is a literal rather than a symbol.

Comment: No, I don't think so because PowerShell uses the exact same engine that C# uses because it is using the .NET Framework. [regex]::Match(...) in PowerShell is *exactly* the same as Regex.Match(...) in C#. It only needs to be escaped if it contains numbers because in that case it is a repetition clause.